# Lucene's incrementToken() last term ignored

Tags: java, lucene

I have been trying to implement a custom analyzer in Lucene. I think I am really close to finishing but I face two strange issues.

First, my filter works as expected for every term in the tokenstream except the last one. (Though I am trying to handle it).

Second, I wouldn't have a problem using that TokenFilter (even missing the last term). But although the indexing is working perfectly (checked the resulting index with Luke), when I try to use my analyzer to parse user queries = the resulting Query is blank(!) Could this be due to the missing term?

I have posted the incrementToken() method of filter below. Any help would be really welcome. Thank you in advance.

P.S. I now that in terms of contribution this question is not good, but i could not find something specific elsewhere.

```
public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    if (!input.incrementToken()) {
        if (previousTokenFlag) {
            tempPreviousToken.attSource.copyTo(this);
            previousTokenFlag = false;
            this.incrementToken();
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (previousTokenFlag) {
        if (CheckIfMainName(this.termAtt.term())) {
            if (CheckIfMainName(tempPreviousToken.termAtt.term())) {
                termAtt.setTermBuffer(tempPreviousToken.termAtt.term() + 
                       TOKEN_SEPARATOR + this.termAtt.term());
                this.setPreviousTokenFlag(false);
                return true;
            } else {
                tempHelpingToken = new TempToken(this.input.cloneAttributes());
            }
            tempPreviousToken.attSource.copyTo(this);
            tempHelpingToken.attSource.copyTo(tempPreviousToken.attSource);
            return true;
        } else {
            if (CheckIfMainName(tempPreviousToken.termAtt.term())) {
                tempHelpingToken = new TempToken(this.input.cloneAttributes());
                tempPreviousToken.attSource.copyTo(this);
                tempHelpingToken.attSource.copyTo(tempPreviousToken.attSource);
                tempHelpingToken.attSource.clearAttributes();
                return true;
            } else {
                tempHelpingToken = new TempToken(this.input.cloneAttributes());
                tempPreviousToken.attSource.copyTo(this);
                tempHelpingToken.attSource.copyTo(tempPreviousToken.attSource);
                tempHelpingToken.attSource.clearAttributes();
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        tempPreviousToken = new TempToken(this.input.cloneAttributes());
        tempPreviousToken.termAtt.setTermBuffer(this.termAtt.term());
        this.setPreviousTokenFlag(true);
        this.incrementToken();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am really sorry for that , you are right. Also i think i solved it i will post the code  (cleaned) later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but the first lines of you filter look wrong:

```
        tempPreviousToken.attSource.copyTo(this);
        previousTokenFlag = false;
        this.incrementToken();
        return false;
```

First, you copy your *tempPreviousToken* to the current token (`tempPreviousToken.attSource.copyTo(this)`), and then you always return false, giving no chance to the current token to be ever used. You should either return false directly, or return true/false depending on the token you tried to copy.